# reading from tsv file in java

Tags: java, csv

I am reading every line from tsv file using buffered reader in java, then storing it in array and printing the array. But records print from middle of the file and not the start.

```
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        UserItemsTsvParser u=new 
        UserItemsTsvParser("./data/user_items/users_movies.tsv");
        ItemsTsvParser a =new ItemsTsvParser("./data/items/books.tsv");
        while(!(a.hasReachedEndOfFile()))
             {

                a.readNextLine();

             }  
    }
}
```

and I am calling methods from another class:

```
public ItemsTsvParser(String relativeFilePath) 
        throws IOException {        
    fileReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(relativeFilePath));
    System.out.println(relativeFilePath);
    currentLine=fileReader.readLine();

}

/**
 * It reads the next line of the file.
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 */
int i=0;
public void readNextLine() throws IOException {

    while((currentLine=fileReader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.print(i++);
        currentLineTokens=currentLine.split("\t");
        currentItemId=currentLineTokens[0];
        currentItemType=currentLineTokens[1];
        currentItemUri=currentLineTokens[2];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currentLineTokens));
    }
}

/**
 * Returns TRUE if EOF has been reached by the reader.
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public boolean hasReachedEndOfFile() throws IOException{

    if(currentLine==null)
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is currentLine a class or something? I don't see it defined it anywhere.

Comment: If this is not homework, you may also consider using [Apache Common CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) to parse the TSV file. Its parser supports both CSV and TSV as far as I understand

Comment: `ItemsTsvParser` throws away the first line of the input file.  Does line #2 constitute the "middle" of the file?

Comment: @edwindalorzo, a CSV parser won't be able to read TSV properly. See my reply to this question.

Comment: @JeronimoBackes Do you have evidence or you think so? Because Apache Common CSV documentation [explicitly says](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html) it supports [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) files. I haven't tried it myself, I just want to make sure it wasn't that you thought it only supported CSV files.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I've got evidence: try parsing the String "b\\tc\tc\\n\\d" with `CSVFormat.TDF` and you will get "b\tc" where the escaped tab was not read as a tab character but slash followed by the character 't'. You will also get "c\n\d" where newline is also not unescaped, it produces a slash caracter followed by the letter 'n', instead the actual line ending character.

Comment: @Jeronimo Technically that's not TSV since "\\t" is not a tab.

Comment: @edwinDalorzo this was meant to be \\ (i.e. an escaped slash) followed by the letter t, inside a string, not slash followed by a tab character. Sorry I didn't realise it wasn't clear. In TSV the slash followed by a t represent and escaped tab character - we can't use the tab itself in TSV as the TSV format does not support quotes. That's why a CSV parser can't be used when reading TSV. Also a TSV is a standard format (it's a IANA MIME type) while CSV doesn't have any standard to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

`.split("\t");` is a very slow operation. In addition, your solution will fail in case some field has escaped characters such as `\` followed by tab (`\t`), or if there is a `\` followed by the letter `t`.

Don't use a CSV parser because it won't handle this sort of thing either, you need a proper TSV parser, such as the one provided by [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial).

You could use it like this:

```
//use the settings to configure the parser if required.
TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();

TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File("./data/items/books.tsv"), "UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library, it's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)